# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I created a new database scheme using PgAdmin. But when I start Spring Boot application with Liqudbase dependency I get this error:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: no schema has been selected to create in
  Position: 14 [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE databasechangeloglock (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, LOCKED BOOLEAN NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255), CONSTRAINT databasechangeloglock_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ID))]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:393) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Help us help you - share your code and the liquibase configuration

Answer (score 0):

Generally this exception is due to invalid **SEARCH PATH** or not having necessary privileges.

In most of the cases the first entry is invalid or the search path is empty. Fixing path settings might help solve this. You can follow [this detailed guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777) to fix search path settings.

OR

```
create schema schema_name;
set search_path to schema_name;
create table foo (id int);
```

As far as user privileges is concerned, it is not the best way as you will need to grant permission to every user.

Comment: I found the issue schema name was with capital letters and numbers. After using small letters and numbers it's running fine. I wonder why.